# Json response give null , when multiple word with spaces send with url to json for parsing in android

Tags: android, json

I would like give comment to my Image ,when i give one word as a comment then it successfully saved using asyntask, but when i have send comment like "asas sas asas asas asas asas asas asa " means line with spaces it give null response. 
Please give me suggestions.

My asyntask code is,

```
package com.asyntask;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.model_classes.Model_Image_list;
import com.model_classes.Model_User_info;
import com.model_classes.Model_Video_list;
import com.utility.BaseUrl;
import com.utility.ConnectionDetector;
import com.utility.CustomDialogue;
import com.utility.JSONfunctions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

//DownloadJSON AsyncTask
public  class CommentListAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
{ 
    int flag=0;
    String userID,video_title,type;
    Model_Image_list image_list_info;
    Model_Video_list video_list_info;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Model_Video_list> arraylist_video_list=new ArrayList<Model_Video_list>();
    ArrayList<Model_Image_list> arraylist_image_list;
    ArrayList<Model_User_info> arraylist_user_info;
    JSONObject jsonobjectResult;
    String str_status,action,viewId,comment;
    public CommentListAsynTask(Context context) 
    {
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();


                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        arraylist_image_list = new ArrayList<Model_Image_list>();

        mProgressDialog.show();

    }


    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg)

    {
        this.userID=arg[0];
        System.out.println(userID+".......UserID");
        this.viewId=arg[1];
        System.out.println(viewId+".......viewID");
        this.comment=arg[2];
        System.out.println(comment+".......Comments");
        this.action=arg[3];
        System.out.println(action+".......actionID");

        // Create an array
        arraylist_user_info = new ArrayList<Model_User_info>();


        //Send URL to JSONfunction class in which parsing the JSON data.
        try 
        {
            jsonobjectResult = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(BaseUrl.URL+"commentImageVideo.php?userIdForComment="
                    +userID+"&viewIdForComment="+viewId+"&comment="+comment+"&actionComment="+action);
            System.out.println(jsonobjectResult+"................Result");

            // Locate the array name in JSON
            if(jsonobjectResult !=null)
            {   if(jsonobjectResult.has("error"))
            {
                flag=1;
            }
            if(jsonobjectResult.has("null"))
            {
                flag=1;
            }
            if(jsonobjectResult.has(""))
            {
                flag=1;

            }
            else
            {       
                str_status=jsonobjectResult.getString("status");
                System.out.println(str_status+"..........>Ststus");
            }
            }


        }
        catch (NotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonobjectResult;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) 
    {  
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if(flag != 1)
        {
            try {
                if(response.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("Success."))
                {
                    System.out.println(str_status+".............Comment status");
                    CustomDialogue dialogue=new CustomDialogue(context, "You have successfully Comment");
                    dialogue.show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /*if(str_status.equalsIgnoreCase("Error."))
            {
                CustomDialogue dialogue=new CustomDialogue(context, "You have Already liked");
                dialogue.show();

            }*/
        }
        else
        {
            ConnectionDetector.displaySlowNetworkDialog((Activity)context);
        }

    }
}
```

and my json parsing function is,

```
public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) throws TimeoutException
    {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
            int timeoutConnection = 150000;
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(httpParams, timeoutConnection);
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,timeoutConnection);

            // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeoutConnection);

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = stringBuilder.toString();
                jsonObject=new JSONObject(result);


        } 
        catch (ConnectTimeoutException e)
        {   
            try
            {
                //Create jsonobject for handling ConnectTimeoutException.
                jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"error\":\"ConnectTimeoutException\"}");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketTimeoutException  e) 
        {
            try 
            {
                //Create jsonobject for handling SocketTimeoutException.
                jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"error\":\"SocketTimeoutException\"}");
            } catch (JSONException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection for slow connection ... " + e.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            try {
                //Create jsonobject for handling for null Exception.
                jsonObject=new JSONObject("{\"null\":\"JSON null\"}");
            } catch (JSONException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



        return jsonObject;
    }
```

Comment: In `catch (Exception e)`, print the exception. That will help understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not sure this will solve your problem, try setting %20 for your comment before sending your getRequest.

```
comment = comment.replaceAll(" ","%20"); //escape spaces trim() can also be useful
jsonobjectResult = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(BaseUrl.URL+"commentImageVideo.php?userIdForComment="
                +userID+"&viewIdForComment="+viewId+"&comment="+comment+"&actionComment="+action);
```

Comment: This is likely to be the problem. But better yet, use [`Uri.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks... Using replace All() , it solved,but Matish how Uri.Builder is used.